# Is there a solution if a ribbon client-side load balancing is down?

Tags: spring-boot, load-balancing, netflix-eureka, hystrix, netflix-ribbon

Based on my understanding of load-balancing, requests are forwarded to multiple instances of a service so that if one service is down, it will be redirected to one that is available.

I have created a microservice that implements load-balancing [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COnbo.png) using Ribbon and Hystrix to handle fallback. However, this only works if the load-balancing service is working properly.

What if the load-balancing service goes down? Is there a solution to keep the microservice running so that the instances of the service can still be reached?